# Number of induced graphs

Tags: graph-theory

How many induced graphs has a graph with $n$ vertices?

I think that there are $2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$.Is this correct?

Comment: yeah, correct...

Comment: Dear @M.B. That comment is an answer, so you might consider converting it to one so that this question is resolved. If you feel "yes" is too little for an answer, you could always elaborate a little bit on a clever way of seeing the answer, or else just make it a community wiki. Thanks!

Comment: @rschwieb: sure. Added a little something.

Answer (score 1):

If the original vertex set is $V$ then any subset of $K\subseteq V$ uniquely determines an induced graph. Hence, the number of induced graphs is equal to the cardinality of the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $P(V)$ of $V$. Do you see an easy way to show that $|P(V)| = 2^{|V|}$ without applying the binomial theorem?